Scala problem reading parameter values inside List Classes
Given the Scala List below, I would like to access the values of elements x and y and the entire Page class element. I need to use these values again inside another function.

List(Camp(x=2,UG,Target(List(000f)),List(page=Page(2,4,600,150)),y=8.0))


How to I access these values?
x=??
y=??
page=??
All done, the value of x must equal 2, y must equal 8.0 and the value of page must equal Page(2,4,600,150)
Thanks in advance!

It's not clear what you mean with access. A List is a collection of values. Do you want to access to a specific element in a specific position? Do you want to traverse the list and keep the elements that follow some condition? Could you provide some examples of the inputs and the output expected? If you tried something and it's returning some error or unexpected behavior share it too

@GastónSchabas Yes, I want to access specific elements of the List above. A function I built returns the above list. Now I want to extract only the values of x and y and page so that I can use them again in another function.

So, you have a function with the signature
def yourFunction(param1: Type1, param2: Type2): List[Camp]

and based on the example provided I'm gonna assume that the followin classes are defined in this way
val UG = "UG"
case class Target(floats: List[Float])
case class Page(x: Int, y: Int, a: Int, b: Int)
case class Camp(x: Int, ug: String, target: Target, pages: List[Page], y: Double)


If you want to just get the value of an element of a list that follows some specific rules, you could use find which returns an Option. It will be a Some if the element is found, otherwise it will be None.
val camps: List[Camp] = yourFunction(param1, param2) // your function returning

val maybeElementFound: Option[Camp] = camps
  .find(camp =>                           // we try to find a `camp` element that follow some criteria
    camp.x == 2                           // x == 2
      && camp.y == 8                      // y == 8
      && camp
          .pages                          // pages is a list, so we need to use some of the methods provided by that class
          .contains(Page(2,4,600,150))    // contains returns true if the element passed exist, otherwise returns false
  )

maybeElementFound match {
  case Some(campFound) => // ... the logic when the element is found
  case None => // ... the logic when the element is not found 
}


Again, very helpful. Thanks!
